# jquery hide instances of elements

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle only the ".plus" and ".minus" elements within the div that is slideToggled on the click action.

**HTML**

```
<div class="notification-box-heading">
    This is an Alert! 
    <span class="plus"><img src="http://www.cti-w.com/images/info.png"></span>
    <span class="minus"><img src="http://www.cti-w.com/images/close.png"></span>
</div>

<div class="notification-box-body"> 
    <strong>This is an alert!</strong>
    <p>This is the alert subtext.</p>
</div>

<div class="notification-box-heading">
    This is another Alert! 
    <span class="plus"><img src="http://www.cti-w.com/images/info.png"></span>
    <span class="minus"><img src="http://www.cti-w.com/images/close.png"></span>
</div>

<div class="notification-box-body"> 
    <strong>This is an alert!</strong>
    <p>This is the alert subtext.</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide the all of the element with class notification-box-body
    $(".notification-box-body").hide();
    //hide the all of the element with class minus
    $(".minus").hide();
    //slides the element with class "notification-box-body" when paragraph with class "notification-box-heading" is clicked 
    $(".notification-box-heading").click(function () {
        $(this).next("div.notification-box-body").slideToggle(300);
        $(".minus").toggle();
        $(".plus").toggle();
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/tqD6S/2/**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element being toggled, `.notification-box-body` is *not* the element that contains the `.minus` and `.plus` elements. Instead, the container element is actually the one being clicked, `.notification-box-heading`.

Try:

```
$(".notification-box-heading").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div.notification-box-body").slideToggle(300);
    $(this).find(".minus,.plus").toggle();
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/tqD6S/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(".minus", this).toggle();
    $(".plus", this).toggle();
```

The second parameter defines the scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide the all of the element with class notification-box-body
    $(".notification-box-body").hide();
    //hide the all of the element with class minus
    $(".minus").hide();
    //slides the element with class "notification-box-body" when paragraph with class "notification-box-heading" is clicked 
    $(".notification-box-heading").click(function () {
        $(this).next("div.notification-box-body").slideToggle(300);
        $(this).find(".minus").toggle();
        $(this).find(".plus").toggle();
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxw3j/)